# WPF - single item selection with the expander nested in a listview

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, gridview, expander

In my .xaml file, I have a listview containing an exapnder . The problem is that it  does not allow me to select one single item at a time.

```
       <ListView ....>
             <GridView ....>
                   <Expander ...>
                        <stackPanel ...>
                             .......
                        </stackpanel>
                   </Expander>
            </GridView>
      </ListView>



         Header 1
              - Item 1
              - Item 2
              - Item 3
        Header 2
              - Item 1
              - Item 2
              - Item 3
              - Items 4
```

What I mean is I want to select "Item 1" when I want to. Likewise, "Item 2" if I want to. But what happens is that all the items are selected at once. I mean, "Item 1", "Item 2" and "Item 3" when it comes to Header 1. And, of course, "Item 1 " , "Item 2" , "Item 3" and "Item 4" when it comes to "Header 2". No single item selection is possible.

Could you pls tell me where I have gone wrong and which property I should set in order to get the functionality required ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try WPF:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        x:Name="thisForm"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <ListView x:Name="f_List">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Expander Header="{Binding Path=Key}">
          <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value}">
          </ListView>
        </Expander>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</Window>
```

and c# code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  Dictionary<string, List<string>> twoLists = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
  twoLists.Add("1 List", new List<string>(new string[] { "1.1", "1.2", "1.3", "1.4" }));
  twoLists.Add("2 List", new List<string>(new string[] { "2.1", "2.2", "2.3", "2.4" }));
  twoLists.Add("3 List", new List<string>(new string[] { "3.1", "3.2", "3.3", "3.4" }));
  twoLists.Add("4 List", new List<string>(new string[] { "4.1", "4.2", "4.3", "4.4" }));
  f_List.ItemsSource = twoLists;
}
```